# How to remove the files in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes to delete simulator runtimes?

Tags: xcode

Every answer says to delete /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/* to delete simulator runtimes, but what they don't mention is that even as root, these files are not deletable (Operation not permitted). How do I delete the contents of this folder?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, looks like the terminal environment has a problem. `open .` to open the folder in explorer and you can delete them with the GUI and a fingerprint.